# Is there a filtering function to find links between lists in maps?

Tags: java, yaml, filtering

I am tooling around for fun making a Minecraft plugin. In my plugin, there is a YML configuration containing a list of IP's for each player who has joined the server. I want to be able to loop through the other lists in the config to find accounts that may be associated by one or more of the same IP's.

As a visualization, here is an example YML file (ips.yml)

```yaml
98b7a77b-cd65-4f72-ad91-a6c399f1921e:
   - 127.0.0.0
   - 127.0.0.1
1168c028-de65-4698-bbde-9ae674404829:
   - 127.0.0.1
   - 127.0.0.2
bb88d2ab-2433-4c30-bbb8-e012edc19279:
   - 127.0.0.2
   - 127.0.0.3
ab6cad20-04ff-4317-939e-9af8ff50afd3:
   - 127.0.0.3
   - 127.0.0.4
```

Here is my current filtering function:

```java
private static final Plugin plugin = Plugin.getPlugin();
private static final File file = new File(plugin.getDataFolder());
private static Map<UUID, List<String>> getIPsFromYAML() {
    FileConfiguration ipLog = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(file);
    return ipLog.getKeys(false).stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(UUID::fromString, key -> ipLog.getStringList(key)));
}
public static List<String> getAssociatedIPs(String ip) {
    List<String> associatedIPs = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<UUID, List<String>> ipMap = getIPsFromYAML();
    for (List<String> ips : ipMap.values()) {
        if (ips.contains(ip)) {
            for (String ip2 : ips) {
                if (!associatedIPs.contains(ip2)) associatedIPs.add(ip2);
            }
        }
    }
    return associatedIps;
}
```

However, in this function with this YML file, if you were to pass `"127.0.0.1"` in the method, you would only get a list with `{"127.0.0","127.0.1","127.0.2"}` as it only searches for what matches the original string when I want it to return all of the IP's because they are all linked somehow.

Any help with this would be very appreciated.

Comment: Can you clerify the input and the output of the function?

Comment: What is the Java and dependencies version?

Comment: @DiegoBorba Java corretto-17.0.7 and only dependencies in my Maven project (if that's what you mean) are io.papermc.paper.paper-api v1.20.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT and com.github.MilkBowl.VaultAPI v1.7

Comment: @MaksimEliseev I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Please add your `pom` to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After tinkering a bit, I found that I can use 2 methods - one
> essentially the same as the first and one to loop that function until
> nothing else can be added. Here is a link to the code -
> https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/KUJ

Considering your solution, I improved your code:

```java
public static List<String> getAssociatedIPs(String ip) {
    List<String> aIPs = new ArrayList<>();
    ipLog.values().stream().filter(ips -> ips.contains(ip)).forEach(ips -> aIPs.addAll(ips));
    return aIPs.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public static List<String> getDeeperAssociatedIPs(String ip) {
    List<String> checked = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> aIPs = new ArrayList<>(getAssociatedIPs(ip));
    checked.add(ip);

    while (!aIPs.isEmpty()) {
        List<String> uncheckedIPs = aIPs.stream().filter(i -> !checked.contains(i)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        for (String uncheckedIP : uncheckedIPs) {
            checked.add(uncheckedIP);
            List<String> associatedIPs = getAssociatedIPs(uncheckedIP);
            aIPs.addAll(associatedIPs);
        }
        aIPs.removeAll(checked);
    }
    return checked;
}
```

Improvements:

- **Stream Usage**: The code has been rewritten to use `Streams`,
  making it clearer.
- **Minimization of Loop Usage**: Instead of using explicit loops, the
  method utilizes `Stream` functionality to process associated `IPs` more
  efficiently.
- **Reduction of Temporary Lists**: Rather than creating a new list for
  unchecked `IPs` in each iteration, the code maintains the list `aIPs`
  and removes the already verified `IPs` during each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

After tinkering a bit, I found that I can use 2 methods - one essentially the same as the first and one to loop that function until nothing else can be added. Here is a link to the code - https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/KUJ